# Making function for php condition statement

Tags: php

i'm new to php, i'm making Online Cart website in php with admin panels, i've 3 type of users 
1: admin (all roles)
2: sellers (who will sell their items)
3: customers/buyers (who will buy items)

```
        function user_access($user){
        $_SESSION['access'] == '$user';
        return $user;
    }


    if(user_access('admin')){
        echo "you are logged in as admin";
    } else { echo "undefine access"; }
```

but its outpul is same :( how i can make functions for this type of conditions, like wordpress.

sorry for my bad english,

Comment: `return $_SESSION['access'] == $user;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
function user_access($user){
    $_SESSION['access'] == '$user';
    return $user;
}
```

should be just:

```
function user_access($user){
    return $_SESSION['access'] == $user;
}
```

So, you need to remove the quotes around `$user`, and return the result of the comparison, not the $user variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
$_SESSION['access'] == '$user';
```

is testing to see if `$_SESSION['access']` contains the literal string `$user`

Change to

```
return $_SESSION['access'] == $user;
```

to test against the value of the variable `$user`

Comment: This won't work as you're still returning $user and not the boolean result of comparison.

Comment: Edited accordingly.... hate it when there's two errors in the code and I only fix one of them